# AWS - Api Gateway POST body with Content-Type: text/plain instead json/application to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

> REQUEST: POST body to ApiGateway to Lambda with Content-type:text/plain
>
> RESPONSE: "message": "Internal server error"

Body example:

```
{"a":"first", "b":"second"}
```

Which configuration did i need to change to accept this Content-Type?
For json/application, it works just fine.

Comment: Are you seeing any logs from the lambda in CloudWatch logs? Does lambda logs has this error?

Comment: I'm also seeing this, I'm just setting up a mock integration on API Gateway.. not using lambda at all.. did you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a resource, use lambda proxy integration.

[image]

For more information [read here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html).